# Issue with anchor links when autoLink property is defined in xml

Tags: android, html, anchor

I have already set android:autoLink="all" for textview but when i try to incorporate some anchor link into that text view, anchor links are not shown as link.Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/auto-link-for-textview/

```
 textview.setText("any data");
 Linkify.addLinks(textview, Linkify.ALL);
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Updated:

```
String urlink = "http://www.google.com";
String link = "<a href="+urlink+ ">link</a>"; 

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

tv.setText(link);
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.ALL);
```

Latest:

```
String googleLink = "http://www.google.com ";
String clickLink = "click here";
Spannable mSpannableString= new SpannableString(googleLink+clickLink);
mSpannableString.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"), 0, googleLink.length(), 0); 
mSpannableString.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.example.com"), googleLink.length(), clickLink.length(), 0); 

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  
tv.setText(mSpannableString)
```

Comment: I want to add anchor link along with what you have answered.

Comment: The problem is that i'm not able to incorporate anchor links (<a> </a>) if i've defined linkify in xml

Comment: it is not working when the string is :  String str = "www.google.com click here";

Comment: I want to convert both "www.google.com" as well as "click here" to link

Comment: I think i am not able to make u understand. "http://www.google.com" and "click here" should be two different links

Comment: I think i have to use two textviews side by side

Comment: no, no need to take extra textview. see my latest answer again.

Answer (score 0):

To `Linkify` the text in `TextView` use the below code snippet

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text4);
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Edit:

```
TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    String urlink = "google.com";
    String link = "<a href=\""+urlink + "\">link</a>";
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(link));
    Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: String urlink = "http://www.google.com";
String link = "<a href=\"+urlink+ >link</a>"; 
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(link));

Comment: I want to add this along with what you answered. The problem is that i'm not able to incorporate anchor links (<a> </a>) along with linkify.

Comment: it is not working when the string is : String str = "www.google.com click here"; 
 
I want to convert both "www.google.com" as well as "click here" to link